# Problems to install touchpad-indicator

Tags: touchpad

My touchpad is a little too sensitive so i'm trying to install touchpad-indicator in order to block touchpad while typing.

I managed to install the program, but I can't access to preferences in touchpad-indicator.

During startup it used to have an error message but since I’m really stupid i just checked the box "not show this again" and I’m not able to revert this so I can't post the exact error I’m getting.

Comment: Does it show _anything_ when you try to start it up now?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't open preferences from the indicator menu, you can edit `~/.config/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator.conf`, or use Synaptic to do a "complete removal" and reinstall touchpad-indicator.

Here is the (formatted) output of my .conf file...

```
{"disable_on_exit": false,
 "show_notifications": true,
 "is_working": true,
 "on_mouse_plugged": false,
 "disable_on_typing": true,
 "VertEdgeScroll": true,
 "start_hidden": false,
 "enable_on_exit": true,
 "HorizEdgeScroll": true,
 "natural_scrolling": false,
 "shortcut_enabled": false,
 "first-time": false,
 "TapButton2": 3,
 "seconds": 5.0,
 "VertTwoFingerScroll": true,
 "TapButton1": 1,
 "HorizTwoFingerScroll": true,
 "disable_touchpad_on_start_indicator": false,
 "shortcut": "c",
 "touchpad_enabled": true,
 "CircularScrolling": false,
 "version": "1.1.0-0extras15.04.3-src",
 "autostart": true,
 "theme": "dark",
 "TapButton3": 0}
```

For what you want, set "disable_on_typing" to "true".