# Disabling Touchpad While Typing

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

When I type, I constantly hit the touchpad which makes it click elsewhere. This pretty much makes it unusable for me. Usually I would run:

`synclient MaxTapTime=0`

but I get

`Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`

When running `xinput`, I get the following:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I've tried updating the kernel but unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. There's also no options besides mouse movement speed and primary button under the touchpad settings. I still have the ability to double touch scroll but it's like I have a generic mouse rather than a touchpad.

Running Ubuntu 16.10 on an Acer Aspire V5-573G

Comment: Please add information about your computer model or even Touchpad Modell, if you can. There are different Synaptic touchpads out there. Nobody can help you when nobody knows what hardware you are actually using.

Comment: @mondjunge Sorry I thought I added it when I added the Ubuntu version. In terms of Touchpad model, I'm not sure how to find that out. If there is any other information required, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Install `touchpad-indicator`, it'll do what you want. You'll find it in `Ubuntu Software`, Synaptic, or at <strike>https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator</strike>

update:

direct download of the latest version...

http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu/pool/main/t/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator_1.1.0-0extras15.04.3_all.deb

or add this to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`...

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu yakkety main
```

or install it from the `terminal` app...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

if you have a problem with crashing, your prefs file might be bad, see...

[Error at launch touchpad-indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845219/error-at-launch-touchpad-indicator/845264#845264)

[Problems to install touchpad-indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844694/problems-to-install-touchpad-indicator/844709#844709)

Comment: The current version on their ppa does not work and constantly produces a bug splat. I've managed to install an older version but that just brings up the icon with the cross through the middlle. Enabling the touchpad does nothing when the option is clicked.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie what version does it show up as? It's running fine on my machine. Depending on your version, maybe I have another source for it.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie see my update for alternate locations to obtain the most current version.

Comment: The version coming from the "terminal app" is producing the bug splats. The 0.9x version is the only version that is currently working.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie then download the current version using the direct download link that I gave. It works in 16.10. Also see my other answers at http://askubuntu.com/questions/845219/error-at-launch-touchpad-indicator/845264#845264 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/844694/problems-to-install-touchpad-indicator/844709#844709 as you may have problem with the prefs file.